# Previewing and Opening PDF Documents in Android SDK like IOS SDK

Tags: android, ios, pdf, dropbox, evernote

For PDF files ios platform has `UIDocumentInteractionController` controller and `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` to open PDF documents in another application like evernote, dropbox, google drive etc. Is there a way like this for android platform? I found a sample for IOS in [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130) but could not find a sample for Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-view-pdf-in-webview.html

Comment: Even this one - http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-open-pdf-file-in-webview.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android open pdf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453105/android-open-pdf-file)

Comment: thank you but this is not the solution i'm looking for. because i have dropbox and evernote installed on my device to use with pdf documents but this solution does not care about them. with this way it just show open pdf document with acrobat reader and polaris office. i want more options like open in evernote, open in dropbox etc.

Comment: i tried to use Intent.ACTION_SEND instead of ACTION_VIEW. And get the result nearly what i want. but this time adobe acrobat reader and polaris office options disappeared. is there a way for both lists available? i mean evernote, dropbox, drive, acrobat, polaris etc. i can open document or send document. acrobat reader android application has share option is working with evernote, dropbox and drive. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recomend you look at `MuPDF`. This is open source project so you are free to integrate mupdf with your project, as well modify and distribute it. Developer say that muPdf is small, fast, and yet complete. And it's completly true!

But integrate `MuPDF` with existing android project is not easy. Here a few useful links:

[Official docs](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)

[also look here](http://mupdf.blogspot.com/)

[how to use with existing android project](http://pastebin.com/YzHUhzE7)

Hope it help you

Comment: But if u use MuPDF in your projects, you must release your project in opensource form also or violate license otherways. Comercial license for MuPDF is pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Not used this but you can try it ..

https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview