# Blank screen when attempting load url within app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to eclipse/Java.  I searched for answer but nothing solved my problem.  I hope someone can guide me.  I am attempting to launch a webpage withing an android application however I am getting a blank page in the Android Virtual Emulation.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.t4;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
  }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.t4"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.t4.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

and here is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  The code runs without an error.  I just get a blank screen.  Any help is much appreciated.    Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check if your AVD is on-line? Just go to the browser and try to go to google.com or some other random page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I opened the AVD and just have a blank page.  None of the buttons are doing anything.  I am really new to this so bear with me.  Can you guide me more?

Comment: I clicked the 'home' button it did nothing.  or any other button for that matter,

Comment: Your AVD has not loaded yet. That is you problem. depending on your computer it can take upto 15 mins.

Comment: Thanks DrkStr.  You are right it took a while for it to load.  I can see the AVD.  I got a red border around the screen and now I am waiting to see if the app loads.  so far nothing.  I will step out and check back in 1 hour.

Comment: Hi, I dont know what emulator you are using at the moment(in eclipse), but depending on the computer you have you can use this to get a mroe faster and more responsive AVD. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xea3Ng-cwwg

Comment: Thanks.  Successfully running the app now on my android device.  I am skipping the ADV.  I just need to figure out how to make pdfs open in pdf capable app or inside my app.

Comment: Here this might be of some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453105/android-open-pdf-file

Answer (score 1):

try to put  `myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` // enable javascript

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks.  Did that.  Run it.  Still a blank screen.  Any other ideas?

Comment: yes also put this code  myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
         // do something here
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks Lucian. I am not sure how to use the code that you wrote. I copied and pasted and got errors. I was able to fix one error by changing myWebview.setWebViewClient to myWebView.setWebViewClient (changed the v to Captial V in myWebView). The errors are many errors and  I am not sure where to start.  Do you I need to import anything else?

Comment: Your AVD has not loaded yet. That is you problem. depending on your computer it can take upto 15 mins.

Comment: The ADV machine is really slow.  Ended up running it on my Android device.  Worked but asked me to select which application to open in and I opened the URL in browser.  partial success.

Comment: Got it working using WebView theWebPage = new WebView(this);
       setContentView(theWebPage);
       theWebPage.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [working basic webview](http://colibrifrost.com/android-webview-hello-world/). I tested with "www.google.com" like yours and came up with a blank view. I used "http://www.google.com" and it ran fine. Try that out on yours? But feel free to steal the sample code too.

Comment: Can you please expand on using  ASyncTask to load the webpage in its own thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your app (I mean click Run again) and make sure you have enabled javaScript as mentioned above.