# Select image from gallery for some device it null

Tags: android, android-cursor

i am getting image from gallery from below code

```
 Uri filePath = data.getData();
 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE};
            Cursor cursor =
                    mCon.getContentResolver().query(filePath, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

but when i select image from file explore in some devices cursor is always null but if i select same image from gallery app it works... why it so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code

```
private String uriToFilename(Uri uri) {
        String path = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            path = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(this, uri);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            path = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(this, uri);
        } else {
            path = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, uri);
        }

        return path;
    }
```

create **RealOathUtil.java**

```
public class RealPathUtil {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri) {
        Log.e("uri", uri.getPath());
        String filePath = "";
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            Log.e("wholeID", wholeID);
// Split at colon, use second item in the array
            String[] splits = wholeID.split(":");
            if (splits.length == 2) {
                String id = splits[1];

                String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
// where id is equal to
                String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            filePath = uri.getPath();
        }
        return filePath;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String result = null;
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index
                = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Now in onactivtyResult() use this

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
 String selectedImagePath = uriToFilename(selectedImageUri);
```

Comment: in this how i can get url

Comment: in getRealPathFromURI_API19 it always goes else how i can get cursor from all of the method coz i want  file path then file mine type

Comment: can tell me how i can get pdf mime in this mehtod

Comment: sorry. what you want i didn't get it.please explain a bit

Comment: so from your method i am getting path now i want that path for file ,mime for file

Comment: basically i want that file mime type and path so that i can convert that file to byte[]

Comment: you need to explore MediaStore. to meet your requirment. but i think if you want to open pdf file. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17453242/3593066

Comment: also check this link http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/

Comment: from your when select from gallrey it not showing path .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108924/discussion-between-andro-and-mustanser-iqbal).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: i am using   Intent intent = new Intent();
                                        intent.setType("*/*");
                                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

To open gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        mImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath);
        mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
    }
}
```

To get actual path of image:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: nope in this code it give cursor  null if select image from file exploere

Comment: this is same cod ei have wriiten u can check qus

Comment: Well in my code it gives message that Method invocation cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA) may produce NullPointerException. Not always produce NullPointerException.