# Cannot resolve symbol setDataAndType and setFlags

Tags: android, class, android-studio, syntax-error, symbols

this codes was from another post : [Android open pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453105/android-open-pdf-file)

this is all my codes in 1 class called openFile.class

```
package com.test.android;


import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;

public class openFile {

  String namafile ;
  public openFile(String namafile){
    this.namafile = namafile;
  }

  File file = new
  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+   
  namafile);
  Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
  target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

  Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
    try {
      startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
   }

}
```

any suggestions will be accepted

Comment: All the code you got from that answer needs to be inside a method.

Comment: @MikeM. I will try to put it inside a method later, thanks.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention my goal. I want create this class to open a PDF file after being downloaded to a smartphone. So i just created a method, put that codes inside a method and it works, now the error changed to startActivity(intent); Cannot resolve method 'startActivity(android.content.intent)'

Answer (score 0):

As [@MikeM.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) suggested in the comments:

> All the code you got from that answer needs to be inside a method.