# How to view a PDF file

Tags: java, android, file

I can not read a pdf file with my program. The code is simple but, unfortunately it does not work. thank you in advance

```
    String path =getActivity().getFilesDir()+"/test.pdf";
    File file = new File(path);
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    Intent intent=Intent.createChooser(target,"Open File");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Use MuPdf for android
https://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting

Comment: is it possible that you don't have an app to open this pdf file? Without an error message there could be a lot of reasons.

Comment: Thanks to everyone but I found the solition. The problem is that I use the version of android 6.0 +. In this version it is necessary to manually activate the permission to have access of recording by the program. Ex: settings-> app-> yourapp-> permissions.
Thank you again to all the developer who gave their opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code on how to open that file (test.pdf) with an Intent chooser:

```
File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir()+"/test.pdf");
Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453242/5063104)

Answer (score 0):

[PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) support is added in `Android 5.0`

Below Android 5.0, you have to make a workaround

See this blog written by [CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html)  for viewing PDF

Answer (score 0):

how to open pdf file [click here for complete code](http://androidsrc.net/create-and-display-pdf-within-android-application/)

```
 private void openRenderer(String filePath) {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            try {
                mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,
                        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
                mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```