# how to open pdf from sdcard

Tags: java, android

Trying to open pdf file from download folder on device,
i save the name of file in `firebase` and now i want to check if the file is already found on device and then open it else download from `firebase`.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "filename");
System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

///but when i print Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() i get 
///storage/emulated/0

if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    target = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("file not found");
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: For checking if your file exist you can use FileOutputStream with your file and check with debug when executed and test with add "file:" before your path

Comment: Did you follow the [the guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) ?

Comment: Please refer to this link i think it will helpful for you [Open pdf using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453242/7628524)

Answer (score 2):

try this to get your file from download directory

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + filename);
```

Comment: i did what you suggets but now i get another exeption  FileUriExposedException

Comment: see this link https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0